# Is it true that a matrix is always positive semi-definite if it is positive definite?

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

Is it true that a matrix is always positive semi-definite if it is positive definite?

I think it is not true since I saw a counter-example somewhere.

But the terminology 'semi-definite' and 'definite' seems to imply that 'definite' has strong condition, thus being sufficient condition for semi-definiteness.

So I want to know more detailed mathematical explanation for this proposition.

Comment: Does a number’s being positive preclude it from being nonnegative?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the definitions of semi-definite and definite?  I realise that might sound a little rude, but your question seems to imply you haven't....

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we are operating on the real numbers.

Generally, a matrix $M$ is positive definite if $x^TMx >0$ for any non-zero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and positive semidefinite if $x^TMx \ge 0$ for any non-zero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Therefore, if a matrix is positive definite, it must be positive semi-definite.

**UPDATE**

You may be confusing the idea that if something is positive semidefinite, that means there is some $x$ for which $x^T Mx = 0$. That does not have to be. Any matrix where $x^T M x > 0$ is both positive semidefinite and positive definite.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 &3\\0 & 1&2\\3 & 2& 8\end{bmatrix}$ is positive definite but not positive semi-definite. And according to what you just said, there's still possibility that a matrix isn't positive semi-definite even it is positive definite. positive definiteness don't take into account x=0 while semi-definiteness considers x=0.

Comment: @i9100 the [eigenvalues of this matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+and+eigenvectors&assumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Eigenvector%22,+%22eigvecmatrix%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B3,0,3%7D,%7B0,1,2%7D,%7B3,2,8%7D%7D%22) are all positive. Hence, it is positive definite. It is also positive semidefinite. Also see update

Comment: That matrix is positive semidefinite. @i9100

Comment: I determined semi-definiteness of it by using principle minor and I had some misunderstanding about that method. And now I have clear view what has brought me into contradiction. Thank you for your help.